Is the ‘t’ in ‘witch’ considered a silent t?
I was under the impression that because ‘witch’ ends with a /tʃ/ sound, the ‘t’ is not silent but directly represents an essential element of the pronunciation.
However, a word game (the New York Times game “Connections”) recently claimed that it’s a silent t and I’m seeing multiple people online also claiming that it’s a silent t. As far as I can tell, their reasoning is based on the fact that other words represent the /tʃ/ sound with a mere ‘ch’ spelling (no ‘t’)—e.g., ‘approach’, ‘attach’, ‘birch’. But I would have thought the proper conclusion from that fact is just that English doesn't always use the letter ‘t’ when representing the /t/ sound orthographically (see also ‘hence’, ‘defense’, ‘pizza’), much as it doesn’t always use the letter ‘d’ when representing the /d/ sound (e.g., ‘gel’, ‘jazz’, ‘Taoism’), and so on for other letters and sounds.
So is there another argument for thinking that ‘witch’ has a silent t? Am I wrong about the argument I mentioned? Or is it a mistake to say that ‘witch’ has a silent t? Thanks!
EDIT: I’ll note another question which simply presupposes without argument that ‘witch’ has a silent t, and asks for the origin of ‘tch’ spellings. In general, the discussion doesn’t attempt to provide any reasons for or against this presupposition. The only exception is a downvoted answer claiming that it’s not a silent t because words spelled with a mere ‘ch’ (allegedly) exhibit a small difference in pronunciation (less sharp, more d-like than t-like). The rest of the discussion is about whether certain words spelled with ‘tch’ and ‘ch’ are pronounced with the same sound, about why the letter ‘t’ may occur in the spelling of certain words, and about historical variant spellings of the example words. Again, there is no attempt to prove or disprove the presupposition.
EDIT #2: I’ve already explained why the other question simply isn’t relevant to my question. I don’t know why my question has been closed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Related and possible duplicate.

@tchrist I couldn't find anything in that question to indicate whether ‘witch’ has a silent t (although some commenters presupposed that it does).

The silent letters in witch are  not t but c and h. Neither c nor h is pronounced.

@PeterShor I just added a paragraph making it clear why the other question is virtually irrelevant.

There's no single definition of a silent letter in English. There are lots of types of things that might be called silent letters but if you're asking if something is a silent letter you need to have a specific definition of silent letter in mind.

@StuartF The Wikipedia article you link gives a specific definition that sounds fine to me: “a silent letter is a letter that, in a particular word, does not correspond to any sound in the word's pronunciation”.

I don't pronounce hence and defence with a 't' sound, and  pizza only has one because it's an Italian loanword.

Could you please say why this matters?  As so often, features of English can be signs of the complicated history of the English language and which result inconsistencies of pronunciation of the same combinations of letters.  Have you thought of looking up which and witch in Etymonline, to see if they say anything about this?  As far as I know there is no English word starting 'tch..'.  could there ever be a 'tchocolate bar' or 'tcharge point'?  If there were, would it make any difference to how we say it? Identifying rules for the pronunciation of English are something of a challenge.

@Tuffy: Tchaikovsky starts with a 'tch'. Of course, this is a French spelling of a Russian name, but we don't pronounce it any differently than we would Chaikovskii, which would be a more standard transliteration of the same Russian name.

@PeterShor I've always appreciated the Catalans’ romanization into Txaikovski which works because in their system the ‹x› grapheme represents their own /ʃ/ phoneme, reasonably close to the original [ɕ]. What I don't understand is why nobody seems to write it with a ‹f› instead of a ‹v› even though it gets devoiced there in our own languages as well as in the original. Not sure how folks are supposed to "know" to do that.

I see 'tch' not so much as having a spoken of silent T, but as defining the "ch" with a cha-cha sound, not a chanukah or charade sound.

@Tuffy I’m not sure why any of it matters. I just found the confident claim that ‘witch’ has a silent t very puzzling, and I wanted to know whether it was true. I'm not sure how the word ‘which’ or its etymology (or, for that matter, any etymology) would bear on the issue.

I'd rather ask whether there is an imaginary "t" in "which"!

Does @tchrist have a silent T?

Does "back" have a silent "c"?

I'm glad I'm not the only one who was puzzled by that claim!

There are multiple dialects of English. Each of them has regional variations in "correct" pronunciation. I'm sure that somewhere there is a population for whom "witch" and "wish"  are spoken as homophones, making the T silent or nearly so. But that isn't the most common pronunciation.

@tchrist You think 'wit' and 'witch' are pronounced the same? They are not.

There's no rigorous or official definition of what a "silent letter" is.
The sound represented by the letters "tch" in "witch" is what linguists call an affricate. These are phonetically complex sounds that start with a period of occlusion, which is then "released" with a burst of air and followed by a period of noisy turbulence (frication).
By convention, the International Phonetic Alphabet represents affricates with a sequence of two symbols: the first represents the occlusion, and the second represents the frication. Hence the transcription [tʃ]. But in terms of phonology (the organization of sounds into meaningful units of speech), affricates don't necessarily behave like a sequence of two separate sounds. For example, English words can end in [tʃ], but can't end in sequences of another stop followed by [ʃ], such as [pʃ] or [kʃ] (setting aside marginal cases like loaned proper names). So phonologists generally consider [tʃ] in English to be its own sound (phoneme), not a sequence of the /t/ and /ʃ/ phonemes.
Other systems of phonetic transcription, such as the so-called "Americanist" system, transcribe affricates with single letters, such as [č]. In the International Phonetic Alphabet, affricates can be distinguished from sequences of two separate consonants by using a tie bar (like [t͡ʃ]), although this is often omitted.
The fact that [t͡ʃ] kind of behaves like its own sound is consistent with the fact that it is frequently spelled as "ch", rather than as something like "tsh".
And as you mentioned, since "ch" by itself can represent [t͡ʃ], it's possible to argue that "t" is "silent" in "witch". A competing analysis would be that "tch" is a trigraph where all three letters function together to represent the single sound [t͡ʃ]. In the first analysis, "t" is a silent letter. In the second analysis, it isn't.   I know of no compelling evidence that proves which of these alternative analyses is correct.
Even so-called "silent" E can be analyzed in different ways. The word "rate" is pronounced differently from the word "rat", so the "e" in the first can be analyzed as part of a non-continuous digraph "a_e" rather than as an entirely silent letter. In general, it isn't clear whether "silent" means "redundant (could be removed without changing the pronunciation of the letter)", or "has no obvious correspondence to a single phoneme in the word", or "has no obvious correspondence to a single phonetic portion of the word", or some complex combination of some of these. Letters don't actually correspond very well to pronunciation, especially in English. Some letters are conventionally called "silent" as a means of explaining their non-intuitive behavior, but this is more of a pedagogical technique than a fully defined concept. You could say that "i" in "birch" is a "silent letter", since some people pronounce this word with a syllabic R sound and no phonetic vowel (and the spelling "brch" could conceivably represent the pronunciation equally well), but I've never seen people say that.

If one takes the first analysis (found in your sixth paragraph) to show that ‘t’ is a silent letter in ‘witch’, wouldn’t one also have to take each ‘s’ in ‘bass’ to be a silent letter? Also, would it undermine such a use of the first analysis to note the examples of ‘tetchy’/‘techy’ and ‘clitched’/‘clichéd’, in which the ‘t’ seems to help indicate a /tʃ/ pronunciation?

@76987: sure, you could take either "s" in "bass" to be silent (although not both at once). Or, as Stuart F pointed out, you could take either the "c" or "k" in "back" to be silent. There are practical difficulties with using those interpretations, but there isn't any obvious way to definitely rule them out

I wonder whether (in English) [t͡ʃ] would be better described as morpheme rather than a phoneme?

@herisson Are the ‘tetchy’/‘techy’ and ‘clitched’/‘clichéd’ examples of any significance?

@76987: Those examples just show that in some contexts, whether a word is spelled with "t" or not can make a difference to its meaning and pronunciation. But I don't think that leads to any particular conclusion on whether "t" is a "silent letter" in "witch". The words "now" and "know" are pronounced differently, and the only difference in spelling is that the second has the letter "k" at the start, but I don't think many would argue that this means the "k" in "know" is not a silent letter.

Related to the last paragraph, primary school-aged children in the UK are now sometimes taught the term 'split digraph' for things like 'a_e', which I found very charming to hear a classroom of excited 6–7-year-olds saying.

@MartinKealey: A morpheme is defined as a smallest "unit of meaning": one that can't be reduced to smaller meaningful units. The sound [t͡ʃ] in "witch" would not be analyzed as a morpheme because [t͡ʃ] don't mean anything by itself here, and neither does the preceding [wɪ]: only the combination [wɪt͡ʃ] conveys meaning.

In other words and more succinctly: "It depends what you mean by 'silent'".

@dbmag9 doesn't that cause problems when they graduate to two-syllable words?  Why is the "a" of "rating" pronounced the same as that of "rate" when half of the digraph is missing?

@herisson Or: Since "know" sounds like "no", both the 'k' and the 'w' are silent :)

@phoog: the disjointed digraph "long vowel" spelling rule doesn't specifically need e, any vowel will do. However when it's e there's usually no additional sound for it. Of course this being English, there are multiple spelling rules that can apply, so Peone and Penelope have non-silent es.

@herisson thanks for the clarification

I hadn't thought of the "e" in "bake" as being part of an "ae" vowel which has a consonant stuck in the middle, though viewing the orthography of some vowel sounds as consisting of a pair of vowels, the second of which is swapped with following consonant(s), would make sense for words like "fire" and "fiery" (with the swap not being performed in the latter because it would seem to create an "ey" vowel).

Perhaps a comedy answer but honestly, I’ve always thought that “which” has a missing “t” whereas “witch” is perfectly sensible as written. Nothing silent there.
In my view , it’s the ones WITHOUT the “t” that are the oddities !
Though people from the English town of Norwich may disagree. 
(They have silent w issues to address though)

How do you feel about words that start with /tʃ/? Do "choose", "chip", "chuck", etc., all have missing T's?

I don’t hear the t sound in those. It seems to only occur after a vowel.

@JudyD: What about e.g. "rechuck" [to reinstall a drill bit]?

Apart from the fact that a few Americans still aspirate the /h/ in which (long gone in BrE), the full Oxford English Dictionary gives exactly the same pronunciations for both witch and which...
which  British English  /wɪtʃ/
witch  British English  /wɪtʃ/
which  U.S. English  /(h)wɪtʃ/
witch  U.S. English  /wɪtʃ/
So, yes - the /t/ is always enunciated, even if it's not in the orthography.

Right, but I'm not sure how that's supposed to bear on the question of whether ‘witch’ has a silent t.

Erm... the clue is in the fact that all four phonetic transcriptions include the /t/ - even if it's not in the spelling.

So are you agreeing with the opinion mentioned in my first sentence?: “I was under the impression that because ‘witch’ ends with a /tʃ/ sound, the ‘t’ is not silent but directly represents an essential element of the pronunciation.” I’m honestly confused about which position you’re espousing.

I'm not a linguist, but my initial impression is it's impossible for most native Anglophones to avoid enunciating a /t/ in which, witch (or to hear whether it's present or not, if speakers of some other language can differentiate the two words). Just as it's impossible for most Anglophones to enunciate (or hear) any difference between prints and prince (and I got that from Steven Pinker, who is a linguist).

I’m inclined to agree, but I’m still not sure what your position is. Do you think that ‘witch’ has a silent t, or that it doesn't have a silent t?

I don't know how to answer that. Do I think prints has a "silent /t/"? Or do I think that prince includes a /t/ that's not in the orthography? I have no idea. I just know I can't tell the difference between which and witch, or between prints and prince. But it would need a linguist with an oscilloscope to answer your question.

So Scots with /wh/ are no longer British? :) // Research has shown that native speakers of English do ɴᴏᴛ perceive individual phonemes that phonetically are consonantal affricates or vocalic diphthongs as being somehow decomposable into separable sequences of multiple distinct pieces. Moreover there is experimental evidence that they are right: carefully analysing resulting sonograms proves that the sounds of affricates and diphthongs are co-articulated to produce distinct phonologic effects that ᴄᴀɴɴᴏᴛ be exactly reproduced merely by saying each bit separately and running them back to back.

Is the "k" in "back" silent? Is the "c" silent? Ultimately "silent letter" isn't a clearly defined thing, even if it might (perhaps) have some value in explaining the complexities of English spelling to a small child.

The aspirated /h/ is alive and well in Britain, and also here in Australia. A minority pronunciation, certainly – just as in the US – but definitely not "long gone".

@ChappoHasn'tForgotten: You're welcome to your opinion. I'm old enough to remember when aspirated /h/ was relatively common (in BBC broadcasts, for example). But the full Oxford English Dictionary very specifically doesn't include it today as a BrE pronunciation - they only list it as AmE, exactly as copied into my answer. I can also remember TV comedy programs from the 70s mercilessly mocking the usage, so people pretty soon gave it up! In the US, that mockery didn't happen until Family Guy's Cool wHip skit decades later.

@FumbleFingers Not just my opinion. Some other British E&LU users attest to their own current non-merger. Kate Bunting: "I (UK speaker) would only use the 'hw' pronunciation if I wanted to distinguish clearly between, say, Wales and whales." (I too drop the /h/ based on context, register etc). Kaz Dragon: "I pronounce which and witch differently." /ʍ/ is no doubt disappearing (e.g. my son & 2 of 4 siblings have merged), but it's incorrect to say it's "long gone".

@ChappoHasn'tForgotten: Like I say, you're welcome to your opinion, along with anyone else who thinks it's still credible to aspirate the /h/ in whale (which I confess I've never heard in my life). But my opinion reflects what the full Oxford English Dictionary says, and that's pretty much the world's leading authority on such matters. I take it you wouldn't have laughed at the Family Guy piss-take of those few Americans still aspirating Cool Whip almost 20 years ago ("Barely Legal", Family Guy S05E08, aired December 17, 2006).

@FumbleFingers you're veering towards ad hominem with comments like "thinks it's still credible" and "you wouldn't have laughed". Let's keep it polite, shall we? The full OED is the go-to authority, but it can't cover all regional variations, or remnant usages in older generations. I don't use /ʍ/  inwhale; I do use it in what when I enunciate my words, but like most people I can be lazy in my pronunciation. I do laugh at piss-takes, especially of pretentiousness (eg Stewie's Cool Whip), but I see no humour at all in taking the piss out of the socioeconomically disadvantaged.

The merger is essentially complete in England, Wales, Australia, South Africa, West Indies, New Zealand and most regions of the United States. I hadn't realized you associate it with "the socioeconomically disadvantaged", and until just now I thought you were at least British, if not actually English. When I was growing up in UK SE, the only context where I heard /hw/ was upper middle class speakers on BBC TV/radio. By the 90s I only heard it in an English accent in comic TV characters like Hyacinth Bucket ("aspirational" middle class).

According to LPD (Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, 2008) the trigraph "tch" is regularly pronounced /tʃ/; this means that "tch" is not considered as t followed by "ch", and therefore there is no question about a silent t.
LPD, p. 116 (spelling-to-sound)
Answer to comment from user 76987:
"I’m very confused. I never said anything about whether it’s a matter of convention, and I never asked about why any convention was chosen. I honestly don’t know whether you’re arguing that ‘witch’ does or doesn’t have a silent t."
I am not arguing in the absolute, and that is so because there is no recognizable absolute (perhaps no reseach has been done or if some research has been done it yielded nothing, and in any case there is no result available in non specialized literature). I am arguing that according to a widely accepted convention, there is no logic that makes sensible a question about t being silent or not in words like "witch". At some point in time in the past, linguists have decided to try to see what kind of principles could be found in the pronunciation; that is an endeavour that does not date from very far back in time, it started in the US probably with the efforts of Noah Webster to standardize the pronunciation in the 1780's or so (Noah Webster's standardization of sound). In those days, these early scientists, or perhaps a little later other inquiring minds, were first confronted with words such as "witch" and "which", and they found only one pronunciation for "tch" and "ch". They had a choice to make; whether  it was on the basis of historical fact or not (you do not have in all cases historical facts that will allow you to make the most judicious choice), someone decided that a good  approach was to consider that there was two consonant clusters and a single sound, and that it was only needed to consider that this single sound was that of the two clusters. There was the other possibility of considering that t was silent in "tch", and obviously not many people chose that path. Today, people who ask about this t being silent are no professionals of the English language although there are those who understand this matter to a certain extent (see the first answer to the question "why is t silent?" in the Quora site).
This decision, to say that t is not silent but that instead in the cluster "tch" t has no incidence of its own (to the contrary of t in "often") and is just part of a group of letters that takes on an "assigned" pronunciation, is essentially a convention (a useful one in my opinion).
In the same vein, why do you accept that there should be the sound of t in "ch" (since there is no letter t in "ch") and why is c silent? C has no incidence of its own in most occurrences of the combination "ch", which as a digraph is considered  to have regularly the pronunciation /tʃ/; it is not silent and it is just part of the digraph "ch". In the same way that you can accept that there is the sound /t/ in "ch" you can accept that the sound  /tʃ/ is in "tch".
I hope this clears any misunderstanding you might have had, but if there  remains blurred ideas in your mind do not hesitate to ask again (but try to be very specific, although there is no certitude that I'll have anything useful to say).

I’m not sure what you mean by saying that “there is no question about a silent t”: people often claim that it is a silent t, but I’m asking whether it really is a silent t. Also, as far as I know, nobody has claimed that ‘tch’ is properly analyzed as a /t/ sound followed by some sort of ‘ch’ sound, so I’m not sure what’s supposed to follow from that claim’s falsehood.

@76987 I agree that this is a matter of convention; the convention I mention is that "tch"  is a group of letters that is always pronounced in a unique way, and so this sound is said to be the sound of the combination. (Consonant trigraphs are three consonants that make one sound when next to each other. The two most common consonant trigraphs are DGE and TCH. ) trigraphs. Why this convention was chosen is another matter.  However the definition  is not strict ("nch" in "lunch" can be called a trigraph).

I’m very confused. I never said anything about whether it’s a matter of convention, and I never asked about why any convention was chosen. I honestly don’t know whether you’re arguing that ‘witch’ does or doesn’t have a silent t.

@76987 I placed my explanations concerning your last comment in my answer.

Some people pronounce "witch" the same as "which", that is, making the "t" silent. Others pronounce the "t", "witch".
Your examples of words where "ch" makes a "tch" sound puzzle me. I and peole I speak to don't pronounce any of these words with a "t" sound. We don't say "ap-prōtch", we say "ap-prōch". But ignoring that, even if these words were pronounced with a "tch" sound, I agree with you that that would not make it valid to say that the "t" in "witch" is silent. It just means that there is more than one way to express the same sound in English -- hardly a novel insight.

As far as I know, ‘witch’ and ‘which’ are always pronounced with the exact same ending sound: /tʃ/. How do you pronounce ‘which’? As for ‘approach’, Longman Pronunciation Dictionary has it as /ə 'prəʊtʃ/ or /ə 'proʊtʃ/. Do you pronounce it differently?

I have heard people pronounce "which" with no "t" sound. Go to https://www.thefreedictionary.com/which. At the top of the page there are two pronunciation icons, a US and a UK, both of which have a "t" sound. But scroll down to the next pronunciation icon and I don't hear a "t" sound in that one.

If you mean the pronunciation icon immediately before “pron. 1. What particular one or ones”, I still hear that as ending in /tʃ/. It certainly doesn't sound the same as ‘wish’.

No, not as "wish", but as "wich". Still a hard sound, but I don't hear a "t".
